# Python removes quotes

Tags: python, sql, tkinter, oledb

I'm trying to make a simple gui with tkinter utilizing windows built-in search functionality. This is the code I'm having issues with.

```
#gets search keywords from user input and splits into list
keyword_list = self.entry.get()
    keyword_list = keyword_list.split()

    #creates empty string
    keyword_string = ""

    #fills empty string with list, appends necessary quotation marks
    for i in keyword_list:
        keyword_string += "\"" + i + "\""

    print(keyword_string)

    #runs cmd query of windows index
    subprocess.call("c:/users/jdoe/desktop/wssql.exe " +
                    "\"select system.ItemPathDisplay from systemindex
                    where contains(*,'" +
                    keyword_string +
                    "')\"")
```

With that code, if I enter two keywords into the input field, say "test1" and "test2", python will print keyword_string as this:

"test1""test2"

but, when keyword_string is used in the query it shows up as this:

test1test2

So, somewhere after the print command, Python is stripping the quotation marks from the strings?

Comment: Where is `testvariable` defined?

Comment: I'm sorry. That was an error from lazy proofreading. Should read "keyword_string". Will fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using two sets of quotation marks? Or a set of single quotation marks inside of a set of double quotation mark?

Comment: Using single quotes inside doublequotes works!

I tried all the varieties of quotes within quotes I know of, and thought I'd share what happened with the others.

Escaping them concatenates the two strings and strips the quotes somewhere between being printed and being sent to the query.

Using triple quotes leads to the strings just disappearing and the query being empty (also the last paranthesis of the query disappears, which I found really odd).

Using doublequotes inside single quotes concatenates the strings and strips the last quotation mark, but not the first (again, I find that odd).